# Agregar valores a arreglo con evento onBlur

Tags: reactjs

Amig@s, estoy realizando una aplicación con `ReactJS` -mi primera aplicación con este lenguaje, por lo que si ven algo poco eficiente me lo hacen saber (:-, en el cual tengo un modal donde agrego inputs automáticamente mediante el evento `onChange`. Quiero agregar lo que se escribe en estos inputs a un arreglo para después poder enviarlo a una `API`. Me está costando más de lo normal, ya que imagino que `ReactJS` trabaja de alguna forma especial que aún no alcanzo a dimensionar.

```
const addFields = (event) => {
   const input = event.target.name.split(' ')
   const id = fields.findIndex(x => x.id === input[1])

   if (id < 0) {
      console.log(`value ${event.target.value}`)
      setFields(fields.concat({
         id: input[1],
         name: input[0] === 'fieldname' ? event.target.value : null
      }))
   }
   console.log(`fields ${fields}`)
}
```

Mediante este evento puedo obtener los valores pero siempre me omite el primer input, ignoro porqué =/.

Agrego el código del modal por si lo necesitan

```
return <Modal size={props.size} show={props.isOpen} onHide={props.close} onEntered={loadMethods}>
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Crear Endpoint</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
        <Form>
            <Table striped bordered responsive>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th className="text-center">Nombre</th>
                        <th className="text-center">Requerido</th>
                        <th className="text-center">Origen</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {initialInput.map((k, i) => {
                        return <tr key={i}>
                            {/* Field name */}
                            <td>
                                <Form.Group as={Row}>
                                    <Col sm={12}>
                                        <Form.Control type="text" name={'fieldname ' + i} onBlur={addFields} onChange={() => { addInput(i + 1) }} />
                                    </Col>
                                </Form.Group>
                            </td>
                            {/* Required */}
                            <td>
                                <Form.Check type="switch" id="isRequired" label="Sí" name="required" onChange={handleChange} />
                            </td>
                            {/* Origin */}
                            <td>
                                <Form.Group as={Row}>
                                    <Col sm={12}>
                                        <Form.Control as="select" name="origin" onChange={handleChange}>
                                            {origin.map((o, i) => {
                                                return <option key={i} value={o}>{o}</option>
                                            })}
                                        </Form.Control>
                                    </Col>
                                </Form.Group>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </Form>
    </Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="outline-secondary">Cancelar</Button>
        <Button type="submit" variant="outline-success" onClick={save}>Guardar</Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
</Modal>

Un plus excepcional sería que me indicarán como puedo agregar objetos a un arreglo cuando no exista y como modificar uno ya existente dependiendo de un id particular.
```

**Actualizacion**

Adjunto ejemplo en **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1xqflz?file=Hello.js)** para mejor entendimiento; como veran, ya pude solucionar la actualizacion de un objeto, solo me queda entender y solucionar porque el primer input que pierde el foco no es agregado de inmediato en el arreglo

Espero haber sido lo más claro posible. Como siempre, cualquier ayuda se agradece!

Comment: Puedes comprobar mientras reviso el resto mas a fondo que no esté dándote problemas por estar declarando una variable ya existente dentro del scope?
`{initialInput.map((k, i)  // i
{origin.map((o, i)  // i otra vez
```

Comment: Que variable esta repetida? el `i`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se hace complicado en si mismo la manera en la que entiendo estás planteando esto, voy a compartirte como he solucionado algún caso parecido para que te sirva de guía o ayuda.

Con respecto a que te omite el primer input, miraría por aqui, le está pasando como primer elemento 1 y no 0.

```js
addInput(i + 1)
```

## Gestion de formulario en el estado

#### Fields

`fields` cambiamos el tipo de ser una lista [] para ser un objeto {}.

`setFields` se encarga de insertar el registro en el objeto con lo que ya no tienes que preocuparte por duplicados, cada input tendra su propia clave en el objeto con el nombre del campo `name` del mismo. Y si se volviera a cambiar al ser la misma clave, solo actualiza su valor.

#### onChange

Éste método lo único que tiene que hacer es actualizar el objeto.

```js
const addFields = (event) => {
   const { name, value } = event.target;
   setFields(state => ({ ...state, [name]: value }));
}
```

Esto te permite construir tu formulario dinámicamente y una vez que quieras enviarlo a la API, ya lo tienes disponible de la siguiente forma:

```js
{
  fieldname1: "el valor del input",
  fieldname2: "el valor del input2",
  ...
}
```

## Agregar objeto a un arreglo cuando no exista

Primero necesitamos saber si ya existe, para lo que buscamos en la lista el item. Para lo que podemos crear una función

```
const findIndexByProp = (array, prop, value) => array.map(a => a[prop]).indexOf(value);

const lista = [{ id: 1, value: 1}];
const indice = findIndexByProp(lista, 'id', 1);
console.log(indice); // 0

if (indice > -1) {
  //La lista no contiene el elemento
}
```

## Modificar item ya existente en una lista

Buscamos con el método anterior el índice y con el lo siguiente:

```
const lista = [{ id: 1, value: 1}];
const indice = findIndexByProp(lista, 'id', 1);
const newItem = { id: 1, value: 2 };
lista.splice(indice, 1, newItem)
console.log(lista) // [{ id: 1, value: 2 }]
```

[Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: El escenario es un poco complejo, por eso no se entiende bien. Fue una interesante propuesta, probé sacando el +1 pero no funcionó. Pasa que el initialInput debe tener un array con al menos un elemento para inicializar el formulario con un input.. a medida que vas escribiendo en ese input te genera el otro que sería el i + 1 = 1..2.... y así. En cuanto al fields, necesito que sea un arreglo porque tengo que guardar objetos dentro de ese arreglo

Comment: Para eso puedes usar `Object.keys` para coger las claves. También puedes inicializar el primer campo en la inicialización. `useState({ id: "fieldname1", value: "" })`

Comment: Es lo que estoy haciendo, mi real problema pasa porque el primer input siempre es ignorado cuando le saco el foco, si escribo en el segundo input me toma el valor del primero, y así va

Comment: prueba a pásarle al input `autoComplete=""` y/o `autoFocus (solo al i === 0)

Comment: Mismo resultado :/

Comment: Solo queda ver el resto del código a ver... si montas un sandbox lo vemos.

Comment: Vere si puedo realizar un ejemplo con StackBlitz

Comment: Ejemplo agregado a la pregunta, te agradezco el interes :)

Comment: Te dejado una propuesta [https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1xqflz?file=Hello2.js](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1xqflz?file=Hello2.js) a ver si te sirve ;)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105780/discussion-between-paulo-urbano-rivera-and-adolfo-onrubia).